# Access 2010 - Check data in recordset before adding new record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm new to Access so bear with me here.

I have a form that allows me to add new data to a table

```
ID  | Name |  City  | Zip Code
1   | John | Newark | 12340
2   | Alex | Boston | 98760
```

So on and so forth...

Before proceeding to add a new record with the above data fields, I need to create a check that will look at the table to determine if the combinations of Name, City and Zip Code already exist.  If they do, I want it to Exit Sub; Else continue with the rest of the macro.

I've been looking to build this using some form of the OpenRecordset command, but I'm not sure where to begin.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: Rather than coding to check it.  You can make the fields you want no duplicates of a composite key.  This will allow for that specific entry to only be entered once.

Comment: What relation does this table have to other entities?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The table is linked to others by the Name field only.  I'm assuming your method will be able to handle a larger dataset with many more fields as well? I'm hoping to have the fastest possible solution as I think this may grow to be a significantly larger table. Thanks again.

Comment: If the name is being stored in the other table, I would link this via that primary key from that table rather than name. It makes it harder to keep the data current within all the tables. If you did that then you could use a composite key to where only one record could exist with name city and zip.  If you normalize your tables and use key relations, it makes scalability and maintainabiliy easier but SQL statements get more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this code to recreate your situation and it worked fine.  You just need to rename your columns and your table in the query.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdf As QueryDef

'if these columns are not text change to approriate type
strSQL = "PARAMETERS [NameToCheck] Text(255),[CityToCheck] Text(255),[Zip] Text(255); " 

'change table name and column names here
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT Count(*) FROM address " _ 
                & "WHERE FName = [NameToCheck]  AND City = [CityToCheck] AND ZipCode = [Zip];"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
qdf("NameToCheck") = txtName.Value 'change to that textfield on form
qdf("CityToCheck") = txtCity.Value 'change to that textfield on form
qdf("Zip") = txtZipCode.Value 'change to that textfield on form

If qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)(0) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "This record is already in the database"
Else
    'Insert statement goes here.
End If
```

Comment: +1 And I think it would be even better with `SELECT Count(*) ... WHERE ...`  Then you wouldn't even need a recordset object variable.  The count would be available as `qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)(0)`

Comment: @HansUp great point out. The tighter the code the better.  Edited the code to impliment that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recordsets as you requested then you would need to use a SQL statement to select all or use it to find something by name.

```
Dim myR as Recordset
Dim strSQL as String

'run a SQL statement to select a record with the same info
strSQL = "SELECT [Name], [City], [Zip Code] FROM table_name_here " & _
         "WHERE [Name] = '" & form_control_name & "' " & _
         "AND [City] = '" & form_control_city & "' " & _
         "AND [Zip Code] = '" & form_control_zip & "'"

'set your recordset to the SQL statment
Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

'if your count is greater than 0, then you'll have a duplicate
If myR.RecordCount > 0 then
    MsgBox "This already exists"
Else
    MsgBox "All clear"
End if

Set myR = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for that. When I try to run this code, it points to "myR =" as an invalid use of property, however.

Comment: @nsjkd Change it to `Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)`

Comment: Sorry, I tried that as well. It gives me runtime error '3061' Too Few Parameters. Expected 1.

Comment: Thanks for that @ObieMD5, I corrected it.  @nsjkd, are you able to just use the `Select` and `From` while commenting out the `where` parameters?  Because your error means something is wrong with the `Where`.  Try making the `Select` and `From` work with a single `Where` parameter also.  I can't help but feel I must've made a typo but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @TKEyi60 My first Where is "WHERE [Zip_Code] = '" & Me.Controls("Zip_Code_Link").Value & "' ".  Not sure if this is making it break.  I structured the following ANDs using that same string.  Basically I'm trying to point it to those specific selections on my form.

Comment: I have always used `WHERE [Zip_Code] = "'" & Me.Zip_Code_Link & "'"` with the zip_code_link usually being a text box.  That may be the issue.

Comment: @TKEyi60 that is why you should use parameterized queries :D

Comment: Anything I can do to fix that? I'm trying CStr to convert the statement in "Forms!" format as well, but it doesn't seem to get past that error.